# Using latest Spring Security with an older tutorial not sure how to correctly override configure method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am following the linked tutorial on spring security and I am not sure how to proceed with the configure method.  https://youtube.com/watch?v=her_7pa0vrg&feature=shares&t=12491

The tutorial's repo has the code below:

```
package com.example.demo.security;

import com.example.demo.auth.ApplicationUserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static com.example.demo.security.ApplicationUserRole.*;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                     ApplicationUserService applicationUserService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/courses", true)
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                    .tokenValiditySeconds((int) TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(21))
                    .key("somethingverysecured")
                    .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET")) // https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/LogoutConfigurer.html
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }

}
```

I am having trouble with this method:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

As the new way of doing things in Spring Security are per the reference page https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

My code looks like the below following the new conventions:

```
package com.quadri.springsecurity.security;

import static com.quadri.springsecurity.security.ApplicationUserRole.STUDENT;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.quadri.springsecurity.auth.ApplicationUserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, ApplicationUserService applicationUserService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
    }


    

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers( "resources/**", "/", "/index.html").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole(STUDENT.name())
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/courses", true)
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .usernameParameter("username")
        .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds((int)TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(21))
            .key("somethingverysecured")
            .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
        .clearAuthentication(true)
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "remember-me")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        ;
        return http.build();
    }

    //configure method I need to implement

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }

    
  
}
```

My users will be coming from this FakeApplicationUserDaoService:

```
package com.quadri.springsecurity.auth;

import static com.quadri.springsecurity.security.ApplicationUserRole.ADMIN;
import static com.quadri.springsecurity.security.ApplicationUserRole.ADMINTRAINEE;
import static com.quadri.springsecurity.security.ApplicationUserRole.STUDENT;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

@Repository("fake")
public class FakeApplicationUserDaoService implements ApplicationUserDao {

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public FakeApplicationUserDaoService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<ApplicationUser> selectApplicationUserByUsername(String username) {
        return getApplicationUsers()
                .stream()
                .filter(applicationUser -> username.equals(applicationUser.getUsername()))
                .findFirst();
    }

    private List<ApplicationUser> getApplicationUsers() {
        return Lists.newArrayList
        (
            new ApplicationUser(
                "annasmith", 
                passwordEncoder.encode("password1"), 
                STUDENT.getGrantedAuthorities(), 
                true, 
                true, 
                true, 
                true
            ),
            
            new ApplicationUser(
                "linda", 
                passwordEncoder.encode("password123"), 
                ADMIN.getGrantedAuthorities(), 
                true, 
                true, 
                true, 
                true
            ),
            
            new ApplicationUser(
                "tom", 
                passwordEncoder.encode("password123"), 
                ADMINTRAINEE.getGrantedAuthorities(), 
                true, 
                true, 
                true, 
                true
            )
        );
    }
}
```

How do I implement the older convention method in my application using the newer style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security picks up `AuthenticationProvider` `@Bean`s by default, so no additional code should be necessary. If that's not working, consider posting a GitHub minimal sample to clarify.

Or, you can publish your own `AuthenticationManager` like so:

```java
@Bean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(...) {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
    return new ProviderManager(provider);
}
```

The reason that the code can be removed is because of how Spring Security deals with precedence. The `HttpSecurity` and `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` DSLs ask "which `AuthenticationProvider` is closest to me?" If one was specified on the DSL, it takes that; otherwise, it looks for a bean.

In this way, declaring a bean is a way to specify a default value for all `HttpSecurity` instances in your app.

Since your app only has one `HttpSecurity`, there is no material difference between supplying the `AuthenticationProvider` on the DSL or publishing a `@Bean`.

Comment: Yes, I can indeed confirm it works without any additional code the way I had above, I tried looking into the AuthenticationManagerBuilder class, as well as, the DaoAuthenticationProvider, but wasn't entirely sure as to why. I understand the annotation @Bean tells Spring to pick it up and configure, but I am not entirely aware of exactly what's being configured for it to work.

Comment: Spring Security processes precedence like this: DSL is first priority, then beans. The reason for this is you might have more than one WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter or in this case SecurityFilterChain. When you set it on AuthenticationManagerBuilder it is  essentially saying "only for this filter chain". When you set it as a bean you are saying "for all filter chains in my app". Since you only have one filter chain, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since this class doesn't extends/implements to any. There is no way to override this method `void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`

You can create that configure method without any annotation but make sure
class gets this import

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
```

```
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(applicationUserService);
        return provider;
    }


 public void configure( AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider( daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```